# The output shown in the screen is not matching with the original result

Tags: c, integer, output, printf

I am a beginner in C

I am facing some problem with this code below:-

> Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 7, b;
    b = a * 0.621;
    printf("%f", (float)b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output was supposed to be `4.347` but, here, the output is `4.000000`.

What should I do to get `4.347` instead of `4.000000`?

Comment: Don't add unrelated tags and image of codes in question.

Comment: You assign the result of the multiplication to `b`, which is type `int` so it gets truncated. Casting `b` to `float` later can't recover the fractional part. It must be `float b;`

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. Actually, this is my very first time in Stack Overflow that's why I didn't know about the rules to post question. I tried my best to edit my question and make it correct. I apologize to you all once again for my mistakesm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the int type to double type , Which can contain a decimal number.

```
int main()
{
    double a=7 , b;
    b = a*0.621;
    printf("%f",(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Out put : `4.34700`

Comment: Thanks for taking time for solving my doubt.

Comment: Please confirm my answer to the community, if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

'b' is of int type, so it will store only 4 and since you are using (float) in print, it will display the value 4 as 4.000000. Change data type of b to float or double.

```
int a=7,b;
```

should be changed to

```
int a=7;float b;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time for solving my doubt.